# How does GOT/PLT work on MIPS?

Tags: gcc, compilation, mips

I'm trying to debug a segfault related to access of the `gp` register.

I've noticed that all functions begin with something like this:

```
0x400b7c <main>:   lui   gp,0xa
0x400b80 <main+4>: addiu gp,gp,31444
0x400b84 <main+8>: addu  gp,gp,t9
```

As explained here: https://www.cr0.org/paper/mips.elf.external.resolution.txt, the use of `t9` seems to relate to a "classic GOT/PLT mec[h]anism".

However, that document is not very enlightening, so my question is:

What is the procedure for deriving an appropriate value of `t9` to use for making a function call? (Assume a runtime code generator / JIT-like use case.)

Update: I found some more complete documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2008-07/txt00000.txt.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the address of the function. The calculation in the function derives `gp` from the function's own address.